# Uncaught NOT_FOUND_ERR: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOMException 8 in Ember while using plupload

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, plupload, ember-components

while using [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) component in ember it seems an error on console, and plupload nor working

> Instantiating FileInput...
>
> moxie.js:3027Uncaught NOT_FOUND_ERR: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOMException 8

i refered [this link](https://github.com/tim-evans/ember-plupload)

thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please upvote my answer if you find it helpful ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element with the **id** **"upload-image"** is needed to match the uploader's **for** attribute

```
{{#pl-uploader for="upload-image" extensions="jpg jpeg" onfileadd="uploadImage" as |queue|}}
  {{#if queue.length}}
    Uploading...{{queue.progress}}%
    </span>
  {{else}}
    <a id="upload-image">Add an Image.</a>**strong text**
  {{/if}}
{{/pl-uploader}}
```